# How to print something after a particular string when comparing two lists?

Tags: python

I am trying to compare string in a list and if the string is also in another list I want to print something on a new line. Unfortunately there are several (the number can vary) same variables within both lists underneath each other and I want to print TER underneath the last one. Where am I going wrong?

```
import sys
import argparse

def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Add Ter records')
    parser.add_argument('infile', help='input file (PDB format)')
    parser.add_argument('outfile', help='output file (PDB format)')
    parser.add_argument('reference', help =' ref')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    resnum_1 =[]
    res_1 = []
    with open(args.infile, "r") as f, open(args.outfile, "w+") as of, open(args.reference,"r") as rf:
        for line in f:
            of.write(line)
        for line in rf:
            if line[0:3]== "TER":
                resnum = line[22:27]
                resnum_1.append(resnum)
                resnum_2 = []
                for i in resnum_1:
                    resnum_2.append(i.strip())
        of.seek(0)
        for line in of:
            if line [0:4]== "ATOM":
                res = line[22:27]
                res_1.append(res)
                res_2 = []
                for i in res_1:
                    res_2.append(i.strip())
                for x in res_2:
                        if x in resnum_2 and (res_2.index(x))+1 != x:
                            of.write("\nTER\n")
                        else:
                            continue

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

`infile` example:

```
ATOM      1  N   GLU D 384      51.765  39.857  23.514  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM      2  H1  GLU D 384      50.823  39.839  23.150  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      3  H2  GLU D 384      51.956  39.044  24.081  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      4  H3  GLU D 384      52.469  39.840  22.790  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      5  CA  GLU D 384      51.934  41.135  24.345  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      6  HA  GLU D 384      53.002  41.062  24.550  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      7  CB  GLU D 384      51.712  42.439  23.503  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      8  HB2 GLU D 384      52.307  42.297  22.600  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      9  HB3 GLU D 384      50.640  42.356  23.323  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     10  CG  GLU D 384      52.024  43.786  24.125  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     11  HG2 GLU D 384      52.138  44.557  23.363  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     12  HG3 GLU D 384      51.201  44.086  24.773  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     13  CD  GLU D 384      53.381  43.828  24.935  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     14  OE1 GLU D 384      53.634  43.069  25.869  1.00  0.00           O
```

`reference` example:

```
ATOM      1  N   GLU D 384      51.765  39.857  23.514  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM      2  H1  GLU D 384      50.823  39.839  23.150  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      3  H2  GLU D 384      51.956  39.044  24.081  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      4  H3  GLU D 384      52.469  39.840  22.790  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      5  CA  GLU D 384      51.934  41.135  24.345  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      6  HA  GLU D 384      53.002  41.062  24.550  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      7  CB  GLU D 384      51.712  42.439  23.503  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      8  HB2 GLU D 384      52.307  42.297  22.600  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      9  HB3 GLU D 384      50.640  42.356  23.323  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     10  CG  GLU D 384      52.024  43.786  24.125  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     11  HG2 GLU D 384      52.138  44.557  23.363  1.00  0.00           H  
TER

ATOM     12  HG3 GLU D 384      51.201  44.086  24.773  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     13  CD  GLU D 384      53.381  43.828  24.935  1.00  0.00           C
```

Comment: Could you provide and example of 2 lists and the expected output ?

Comment: There it it. The outfile is the same as the infile at this point. The output should add the TER record but otherwise look the same.

Comment: In fact I don't understand your example. the line ATOM 12 is exactly the same in the reference file and the infile. Why is the TER before this line ?

Comment: Sorry, its just an example. In real life they will be different after the res number.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, the following snippet should help you.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
b = [1, 2, 5, 7, 16]
streak = False
for e in a:
    if e in b:
        streak = True
    elif streak:
        streak = False
        of.write("TER\n")
    of.write(e)
if e in b:
    of.write("TER\n")
```

> 1
>   2
>   TER
>   3
>   4
>   7
>   TER

It assume elements of list a can be anywhere in list b.
Also note that it does not mark the beginning of sequences... only their ends.

Comment: How do I get it to print into the outfile underneath the last matching e? The res is 384 and there are many 384's in the file. I only want it printed after the last one (when next res will not be 384).

Comment: If the output is what you want. just replace prints by of.write(e) as in your code

Comment: I don't understand. what do you mean by "the res is 384" ?

Comment: So the res variable corresponds to the number 384 in my example of the infile and reference. In your example you have a list of numbers that do not repeat. I will something like this :                                                                                  list =[384,384,384,385,385...].

Comment: oh I put numbers as an example, I was assuming you would consider the full lines as elements.

Comment: Sorry, I am completely lost with this. I just basically want to add the TER record into the outfile when in the reference on that exact spot. But just the TER as the numbers on the line (the last ones will be different and needs to taken from the infile.